# ProGuard, como não mudar uma certa variável

Tags: java, proguard

Eu tenho uma variável no meu código Java, e quero ofuscar o código utilizando o ProGuard, porem tem uma variável que eu desejo manter o nome, apos a ofuscação, pois eu irei utilizar essa aplicação em outros projetos.

```
public static main SwBotIA;
```

essa é a variavel que eu desejo manter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a documentção existem diversos métodos para preservar nomes de classes e os seus membros.

```
-keepnames nome_da_classe

-keepclassmembernames nome_da_classe
```

Veja a [documentação](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#keepoptions) do proguard.